# How to use ujson with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ujson

According to the [official list of built-in libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27), `ujson` is available.  However, the following app.yaml snippet:

```
libraries:
- name: ujson
  version: '1.35'
```

...generates this error:

```
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Error parsing ./app.yaml: the library "ujson" is not supported
  in "./app.yaml", line 89, column 1.
```

If I try to use other supported C libraries like numpy, it works fine.  I am running SDK 159.0.0 (latest) and can even see a "ujson" entry in `google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/appengine/api/appinfo.py`.

Any clue why ujson isn't usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ujson v1.35` was added to the app engine runtime in Python SDK version [1.9.55](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/release-notes#june_21_2017).

This sdk version wasn't included in the gcloud sdk until v[161.0.0 (2017-06-28)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#16100_2017-06-28):

> Updated App Engine components for Python to version 1.9.55. Please visit the release notes for details

---

Anecdote:

Some of us still prefer `appcfg.py update .` instead of `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`.(*We are a rare and dying breed :D*).

So in the past I noticed that the `appcfg.py` tool I was using was an older version from the older app engine tooling. Doesn't come with all the `gcloud components update` awesomeness. You had to download the binaries each time.

`which appcfg.py` should reveal the exact one being used which for me was:

```
$ ~/google_appengine/appcfg.py
```

I can't say I wasn't warned enough. Besides, I kept seeing this advice/warning each time I ran `gcloud components update`:

> WARNING:   There are older versions of Google Cloud Platform tools on your system PATH.
>     Please remove the following to avoid accidentally invoking these old tools:
>
> ```
> /Users/jeff/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py
> /usr/local/bin/endpointscfg.py
> /Users/jeff/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
> ```

So update to the latest version, update your paths to point to the right appcfg, and enjoy `ujson` or any of the goodies as and when they drop.

```
$ ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py update .
```

Comment: I thought I'd leave that _short_-ish explanation for future users encountering similar problems. Might not necessarily be relevant to this question but hey...

Comment: Thanks for all the detail!  A key to this problem was the ambiguity of which tool to use for deployment and the fact that _both_ tools (`gcloud` and `appcfg.py`) come with the [`gcloud` SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/).  While "out of date", I was updating the [_app engine SDK_](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download#appengine_sdk) at a different location than the gcloud SDK, and therefore going unused.